# Store a local year for Date

Tags: java, date

I am going to store only `year` value in Database and retrieve it.

This is my domain (`POJO`)

```
@Entity
public class Publisher {

public Publisher(..., Date establishDate) {
    //assign other variables
    this.setEstablishDate(establishDate);
}

    @NotNull
    private Date establishDate;
...
}
```

And here is my DTO:

```
@NotNull
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy")
private Long establish_date;
```

Here, i am creating a new publisher:

```
new Publisher(..., new Date(this.establish_date));
```

I sent a json with value `1370` for `establish_date` (for post a new publisher) , but in Database it displays as: `1970-01-01 03:30:01`

Why?

And when i Get the `Publisher`, it displays `establish_date` as `1000` !

What is wrong ?

Comment: If you only care about the year, why are you using a `Date` field at all? Why not just use `int`? Note that `new Date(1370)` will construct a value 1370 milliseconds after the Unix epoch - i.e. 1970-01-01T00:00:01.370Z. (It looks like your system time zone is then being applied somewhere...) My guess is that that isn't what you expected. When you retrieve `establish_date` you're finding that the subsecond information is being truncated, which seems feasible. Now, what did you expect 1370 to mean?

Comment: @JonSkeet `1370` is a legal value for year in Iran national.

Comment: But that's not what the `Date(long)` constructor does. Fundamentally it's not clear that you should be using `Date` at all... but certainly you shouldn't be passing a value intended to represent a year in as the argument for a constructor expecting a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong constructor. The argument specifies the milliseconds since 1970 - not a year: [Date(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) You may use the right constructor: [Date(int, int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int))

Note that most of the Date API is deprecated. There are better alternatives like `Calendar` and `DateTime`. Since you are only storing the year you could also use plain integer. This will make a lot easier.

Comment: I need to store it as `Date` rather than `int` , how can i store only `year` with `DateTime`?

My year is not `Gregorian .`

Comment: A year itself is not a single point in time and thus very ambiguous: you are missing at least day and months for any complex calculations or transformations. So i would guess `int` is quite a good fit for you.
IF you want to use some Object you should have a look at LocalDate: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int- . IF you want to use anything of this you have make up day and month: `LocalDate.of(1370,1,1)` . But this is highly wrong ;)